# Need help on macro on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

What should be the correct path in order for me to save into the location i want without always changing the path in every pc? 
If anyone can share a simple macro for it will be great.

Please help. Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't know: what is the correct path? :P You may want to do  a search on [prompting users for paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392482/vba-excel-to-prompt-user-response-to-select-folder-and-return-the-path-as-string#26392703)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to get to the path of the user's desktop for a variety of Windows versions:

```
Sub KommonSave()
    MsgBox Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"
End Sub
```

[image]